# I need help understanding Linked List Algorithm (C#)

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures

I need some help understanding some of the implementation used in Linked Lists.
The major thing I don't understand is what the "public Node next;" statement represents. I'm confused by this because I've never seen a class being used like a Datatype to assign a variable.

does the "next" variable hold all data from the "Node" class? I'm just confused by what data the "next" variable actually references.

I should note that I know how to implement the linked list, I just want to understand it better

Code from my Implementation:

```
class Node
    {
        public int data;
        public Node next;
 
        public Node(int data)
        {
            this.data = data;
            next = null;
        }
    }

    class SingleLinkedList
    {
        Node headNode = null;
 
        public void FrontInsert(int data)
        {
            Node newNode = new Node(data);
            newNode.next = headNode;    
            newNode.data = data;       
            headNode = newNode;      
        }
```

Comment: the `Next`-field just contains a reference to another node, the one next to the current one in the list. You can think of a `Father` himself also has a `Father`. Of course both aren´t the same person, they just **reference** each other.

Comment: `next` is a **reference** to the **next** `Node`. In .NET there is a big difference between **reference types** and **value types** (google for it if you don't know). If it was C, `next` would be `Node *next`.

Comment: Does not contain a copy of the data, but a reference to the next node (think about it like a pointer to the data). If you are curious you can check [LinkedList<T> .net code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/linkedlist.cs,df5a6c7b6b60da4f)

Comment: `next` is a reference, aka pointer, aka **link**. Hence the name - linked list.

Comment: This line `newNode.data = data;` is redundant. This is already happening in the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't understand is what the "public Node next;" statement
> represents. I'm confused by this because I've never seen a class being
> used like a Datatype to assign a variable.

`public Node next;` is only a variable declaration that is of type Node. You do this all the time when you declare a variable. You are only confused because you are declaring a variable of type inside the type declaration itself.

> does the "next" variable hold all data from the "Node" class? I'm just
> confused by what data the "next" variable actually references.

Yes "next" variable hold all the data from the "Node" class. Following is the purpose of "next" variable. As you know, LinkedList contains list of nodes that are linked together. This "next" variable acts as a link and points to next node in the list.

[image]

Above is example LinkedList. This LinkedList contains Nodes A,B,C and D.